# Can't select any object-2.80

Tags: objects

really frustrated here. been using Blender for years but I'm at my wits end. Using 2.80; was working fine, now I'm unable to select anything. Even with a new file and default cube, still cant select anything without box selecting. Was using 2.81 for my project, but suddenly object instancer no longer works or shows up in outliner. I've searched all morning for an answer but nothing. Thanks for any help

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Try [sharing your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: Have you tried left clicking to select instead of right clicking?